# Неоднозначный разбор выражения в синтаксисе C++

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Есть следующее валидное выражение на C++:

```
a+++b;
```

Как его должен понимать компилятор: как

```
a + (++b);
```

или как

```
(a++) + b;
```

[Проверяем](http://ideone.com/G1PZEn):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 10;
    int c = a+++b;
    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c;
    return 0;
}
```

> 2 10 11

Почему это будет разобрано именно так? Как определяется предпочитаемый вариант интерпретации `+++`?

Comment: Я немного подправил ваш вопрос, чтобы он был менее тривиальным и более полезным. )

Comment: @VladD хороший заголовок )

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ага, чтобы знатоки не проходили мимо :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Есть такой принцип - лексема считывается по-максимуму (это называется правилом максимального поглощения). Т.е. читает первый плюс. Затем второй. Есть такая лексема - `++`? Есть. Значит, это `++`. Что там дальше? Еще плюс? Есть такая лексема - `+++`? Ах, в языке такой нет? Значит, это `++`. Следующий плюс - начало новой лексемы... И приоритет операторов тут совершенно ни при чем.

Comment: «научно» это [Maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)

Comment: @ixSci Ну не даются мне эти термины... :(

Comment: Да их и не надо помнить, это стэковерфловится довольно легко. Я до сегодняшнего дня этого термина вообще не видел.